# How to use Deserialize attribute to erased_serde::Serialize trait?

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to add the `Deserialize` attribute to struct `A`. Content's `items` contain `Button` like `CallButton` like below

```rust
let mut buttons: Vec<Box<dyn erased_serde::Serialize>> = Vec::new();
buttons.push(Box::new(
    CallButton::new("LABEL".to_string())
        .set_label("CALL LABEL".to_string())
        .set_msg("MESSAGE".to_string()),
));
```

How can I make this also deserializable so I can deserialize it? Is there a better way? I think I'm using erased_serde wrong.

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[allow(patterns_in_fns_without_body)]
pub trait Button: Serialize {
    fn new(label: String) -> Self;
    fn set_label(mut self, label: String) -> Self;
    fn set_msg(mut self, msg: String) -> Self;
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
#[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]
pub struct CallButton {
    label: String,
    action: String,
    phone_number: String,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    message_text: Option<String>,
}

impl Button for CallButton {
    fn new(label: String) -> Self {
        CallButton {
            label: label,
            action: "phone".to_string(),
            phone_number: "0".to_string(),
            message_text: None,
        }
    }

    fn set_label(mut self, label: String) -> Self {
        self.label = label;
        self
    }

    fn set_msg(mut self, msg: String) -> Self {
        self.message_text = Some(msg);
        self
    }
}

// other buttons implementing Button trait...

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]  // trying to add Deserialize
#[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]
pub struct A{
    content: Content,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]  // trying to add Deserialize
#[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]
pub struct Content{
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Vec::is_empty")]
    items: Vec<Box<dyn erased_serde::Serialize>>,  // ! HERE GOES ERROR
}
```

Error: the trait bound `dyn erased_serde::Serialize: db::models::_::_serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied

Maybe I'll have to implement `Deserialize` strictly

```rust
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for CarouselContent {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let mut content = Content {
            items: Vec::new(),
        };

        let s: Map<String, Value> = Map::deserialize(deserializer)?;

        // dont know what to do

        Ok(content)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what **crates** (and their **versions**), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just changed everything into enums and it works, thanks for reading!

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Button {
    Call(CallButton),
    Share(ShareButton),
}
```